# Не могу правильно произвести парсинг JSON строки

Tags: javascript, json

Есть JSON строка вида:

```html
[{"i":15036,"a":9328.10074,"o":9205.07203,"t":9328.09962,"n":9205.07294,"cc":8953,"d":9156},{"i":15218,"a":9328.04222,"o":9205.15477,"t":9328.04124,"n":9205.15645,"cc":8946,"d":9135}]
```

Далее я ее хочу помещать массив отдельно по каждому значению. Но сейчас нужно хотя бы для примера вывести в alert значение 't' из первого массива. В интернете куча примеров, но именно по данному виду JSON строки ни чего нет. Пытался сделать так:

```html
var polyline = JSON.parse(data);
alert(polyline[1]['t']);
```

но ни чего не происходит. По разному пробовал и без [1], и без ['t']. Ни чего не происходит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так работает, приведите ваш пример с кодом именно не рабочим

```js
a = [{"i":15036,"a":9328.10074,"o":9205.07203,"t":9328.09962,"n":9205.07294,"cc":8953,"d":9156},{"i":15218,"a":9328.04222,"o":9205.15477,"t":9328.04124,"n":9205.15645,"cc":8946,"d":9135}]
alert(a[0]['t'])
alert(a[1]['t'])
```

Comment: Если честно я в смятении, тоже заработало, а тогда зачем нужен JSON.parse() ??? Если с ним не работает а без него работает. И все таки если заменить строку, ответом с сервера в котором JSON строка большая то alert выдает undefined

Comment: Ну честное слово ни чего не менял. В итоге все заработало. Порой такое ощущение что стоит написать сюда свою проблему как она решается сама собой Спасибо этому ресурсу))

Comment: У меня бывает такое что напишешь кому угодно и все начинает работать) А так по идеи надо на будущее смотреть какой приходит ответ, если видите массив используем, индексное обращение, а в объекте по ключу)